# highlight value that is x% higher than preceding value (SSRS grouping)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2012

I have a report that measures average execution per hour.I would like to higlight the hours where executiontime is x% higher then the last. So the reports now looks like this:

```
DATE | Time  | average

8-4  | 11:00 | 4,2
       10:00
8-4  | 10:00 | 12,2
       9:00
8-4  | 9:00 | 5,2
       8:00
```

If x = 25 I would like to highlight 12,2 since it is more then 25% higher than 5,2.

What you see above are groupings: the actual dataset contains details per report:

```
Reportname | Time_of_execution | length_of_execution
```

Comment: You can add a calculated column to the query to get the percent of the increment and use this in a formula for the background color, without showing it in the actual report.

Comment: But  the query contains the details, there is no grouping in the query. All grouping is done in the tablix. How would an extra column in the query help me?

Comment: I could've know that from the post? Check about the [Previous](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156372(v=sql.100).aspx) function

Comment: @Serpiton " the actual dataset contains details per report ". But your suggestion was spot on! Due to the sort order in my report (most recent on top) I actually would need a NEXT() ;) But I've got it licked now, thank you! Could you provide this as an answer so I can give you the points you earned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Previous](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156372(v=sql.100).aspx) function to return the previous value of an expression

With your data it should be something like

```
=Previous(Avg(Fields!Alias.length_of_execution))
```